# Rxjs Subject called next no console log

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have this [codepen](https://codepen.io/no1melman/pen/gJXGbJ?editors=1010) and the idea is simple, each time I call `next` on the `Subject` I want to log it. I do this via a pipe:

```
const state$ = new Subject();

state$.pipe(tap(ev => log(ev)));
state$.next('hello')
```

What am I missing to make this happen?

Comment: You do not subscribe :) `state$.pipe(tap(ev => log(ev))).subscribe()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of expression `state$.pipe(tap(ev => log(ev)));` is a stream (Observable). You can subscribe on the stream:

```
state$.pipe(tap(ev => log(ev))).subscribe();
```

or save for later in the variable:

```
const logger$ = state$.pipe(tap(ev => log(ev)));
...
logger$.subscribe()
```